# Showing a set of the form $\bigcup_{x \in E} [x - 1 , x + 1]$ is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and consider $F = \bigcup_{x \in E} [x - 1, x + 1]$. I know that under the assumption that $E$ is measurable, the set $F$ is measurable, but I can't think of an example where $F$ is *not* measurable. Is $F$ always measurable, independent of whether $E$ is measurable? If not, what would be a counterexample?

Thanks.

EDIT: Measurability is meant with respect to Lebesgue measure

Comment: Measurable for which $\sigma-$algebra ? Borel algebra ?

Comment: Measurable with respect to Lebesgue measure

Comment: Then see that $F$ is a countable union of intervals (even if $E$ is not countable (why ?)), and then $F$ is always measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F$ is always measurable, but it is a bit tricky to argue that this is tha case. The point in here is that if $d(x,y)<2$ then $[x - 1, x + 1] \cup [y - 1, y + 1]$ is a single closed interval.

From here, you can deduce that $F$ is a disjoint union of intervals of diameter at least 2. This can probably be faster proven by looking at the connected components. Show that any such union has only countably many terms.

Comment: If $E=(0,1)$, then $F=(-1,2)$, which is not a disjoint union of closed intervals of diameter at least 2.

Comment: @Ruy ty fixed..